# how do I change realm login format in sssd?

Tags: linux, centos, active-directory, sssd, centos8

I'm trying to figure out how to change my realm login format to allow for lowercase but currently it just seems to work with uppercase?

```
realm list
domain
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: domain
  domain-name: domain
  configured: kerberos-member
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: sssd
  required-package: oddjob
  required-package: oddjob-mkhomedir
  required-package: sssd
  required-package: adcli
  required-package: samba-common-tools
  login-formats: %U
  login-policy: allow-permitted-logins
```

I would like to utilize login format %u instead?

Comment: The very long standing convention is to use uppercase realm name to distinguish the Kerberos realm from the DNS domain. And Kerberos realm names are case sensitive. A lot of existing software expects the realm name to be uppercase (even though it shouldn't). You may very well break stuff by doing this.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right about that. It looks like there was a local user account in the passwd file for the user as well and something was causing a conflict. Removing that allowed login from any combination of case without issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there was a matching local user account in the passwd file for the user that was causing a conflict. Removing that allowed login from any combination of case without issue.